# Trouble With Global and Local Variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know it's a heavily discussed topic, I know there are tons of threads out there about it (I've read them all), but I still Just Don't Get It.

Undefined variables (both local and global) are my biggest problem in Python and I have no idea what I'm doing when trying to fix them. I'll go through and add an x = 0 or a var = func(var) some where and some times it works and sometimes it doesn't. It's incredibly frustrating and I really need some help. I've asked my teacher but it usually takes her a while to get back to me and I'd like to get this thing fixed.

Here's what I'm working on: http://pastebin.com/KTuh7D2p (This is for school.)

Can someone please explain variable thing to me?

I keep getting errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project1-v2.py", line 144, in <module>
    main()
  File "Project1-v2.py", line 12, in main
    itemsSave = tagYell(items, itemsSale, itemsSave)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'itemsSave' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, I would guess that it is because you are trying to use `itemSave` to define itself. This is equivalent to saying something like:

```
x = 5 + x
```

the very first time you define `x`.

You need to give some context as to what `itemSave` is before you can try and use its value.

For example, this program:

```
myNum = 5
x = float(myNum+x)
print x
```

Would give me an error message of:

```
x = float(myNum+x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

This however, would work fine, and print "15":

```
myNum = 5
x = 10
x = float(myNum+x)
print x
```

Comment: Oh! Okay. I remember doing that in an earlier assignment now. (: But how can you get X to print inside a different module later down the line? Just use `return x` ? Or can I do `addX(x)` then pass it as `printInfo(x)`?

Answer (score 2):

So here is the piece of code you are asking about

```
def main():
    print "Welcome to the shop!"
    menu()
    itemsSale = 0
    items = getItems()
    itemsSave = tagYell(items, itemsSale, itemsSave)
    itemsSale = calcTax(itemsSale)
    taxTags(items)
    printInfo(items, itemsSale, itemsSave)
    enterItem = input("To enter another item number, press 1. To end, press 0: ")
    print #Line break
```

This line is causing the error

```
itemsSave = tagYell(items, itemsSale, itemsSave)
```

You are trying to pass `itemsSave` into the `tagYell()` function but it doesn't have a value yet.

Python knows that because you are assigning to `itemsSave` in that same scope ie. `itemsSave = ...` It must be an unbound local variable, so it won't even look at the global variables to see if it was defined there.

Comment: So that means I shouldn't have 

`itemsSave = tagYell(items, itemsSale, itemsSave`

Will it define itself in the `itemsSale = itemsSale + itemsYell`?

Comment: @Chelsea: What `itemsSale = itemsSale + itemsYell`?